# Accessing Website by FTP in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, ftp

I try to connect my website via ftp. I succeed connect the folders by my browser, but in visual studio 2012 I can connect the site just by the local address(10.100.101.100)and not by the remote address.
I get this error when I try to connect in remote address:

> unable to retrieve folder information from the server. can't connect
>   to '(the remote ip address)' on port 21. Check the server name and
>   proxy settings. If the settengs are correct, the server may be
>   temporarily unavailable.

Comment: what do you mean by remote address? is the remote address some sort of proxy for the local address (or perhaps visible to the outside world on the outside of a firewall)? In what way are the local and remote addresses different if they point at the same location?

Comment: The local address is the computers' address as it is defined in the router (like 192.168.1.100), the remote, is the address of my network which you can connect from another computer. I referred the 21 port to my local address in the router.

Comment: So it sounds like the external address is the one visible to computers on the external side of your router. You need to do additional configuration if you want to publish via visual studio from an external location by doing some additional router configuration see http://www.mdjnet.dk/ftp.html

Comment: I did all the router configuration that is required for using ftp. In the browser, and in cmd remote ftp works good!!!! the problem is only in visual studio!

Comment: Turn the firewall off on your computer and try it and if it works you need to ad visual studio to the firewall exception list.

Comment: when I turn off the firewall I get this message:"unable to retrieve folder information from the server. the server unexpectedly closed the connection"

Comment: How can I add visual studio to firewall exception list?

Comment: I think more detail is needed here. What OS is being used on the system that is the target if the publish? If you are testing you would need to turn the firewall off on both the source and target system and if one system is outside your router use the DmZ port on your router firewall for the test. What are you trying to simulate by doing this?

Comment: I use the same computer to log in my ftp site through visual studio. once I do it by the local ip and second I do it by the external. (I need to build a web site for devlopment so my friend will be able to get it's ftp  and then programing together) now I just practice on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is six years old, but still someone might benefit from it. Once you open visual studio, in the start page, go to Open Website.

Then in the resulting dialog box select FTP Site.

In the fields, for "server" give the ip address of your website and not the name. for "Port", give 21. For the "directory", use the ip address and slash like this: "165.63.29.89/". And then use your username and password. You will have your website open and files listed.

**Edit1**:If it doesn't work, do the same thing but use only "/" for the directory. It will work.

Edit2: If the connection is still not established, do the same thing with "Passive mode" selected.

And check the Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/34322t8f%28v%3Dvs.140%29)